# Is there a encryption api's available to encrypt log file while using Microsoft Enterprise Library 3.1

Tags: c#

How to encrypt a string message while it is being logged into the log file using Logger.Write(...) in Microsoft Enterprise Library 3.1. Are there any inbuilt API's in  Microsoft Enterprise Library which does encryption?

Comment: encrypt before calling Logger.Write() ?

Comment: do accept answer if you got the info you want

Answer (score 3):

From msdn : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647732.aspx

The Logging Application Block formatters do not encrypt logging information. Trace listener destinations receive logging information as clear text. This means that attackers that can access a trace listener destination can read the information. You can prevent unauthorized access to sensitive information. One approach is to use access control lists (ACLs) to restrict access to flat files. You can also create a custom formatter that encrypts log information. For information about how to create a custom formatter, see Extending the [Logging Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647508.aspx).

here is implementation of log message encryption : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188689.aspx

Comment: Thank you Pranay. Quick question, the most common encryption technique used in all places is RijndaelManaged, however, stats shows Blowfish is better than Rijndael / AES in performance. Can you suggest the blowfish algorithm or C# code equivalent?

Comment: @Gururaj - sorry to say dont have any idea about equivalent....its better if you ask another question which may help you to get better answer...